# how to deal with reads package javax.activation from both jakarta.activation and java.activation

Tags: java, java-11, java-module

When trying to run one of the modules, I see many messages of this error. For example:

```
java: module org.apache.commons.compress reads package javax.activation from both jakarta.activation and java.activation
```

What should I do?

Comment: Are you sure you’re running on JDK 11? According to my documentation, `java.activation` has been removed, hence, it can’t cause any problems. Which is also the reason why `jakarta.activation` now exports the `javax.activation` package.

Comment: I have `<maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source><maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>` in the parent-pom. Is it enough?

Comment: by the way, I see this error when running in IntelliJ (but I checked and all modules are set to JDK11)

Comment: Well, yes, it’s a runtime error message, not a compiler error. When you run `java --list-modules` on that JDK, you shouldn’t see a `java.activation@…` entry. In contrast to JDK 10, where it is right the first entry…

Comment: Hi! Could you manage to solve this problem? I have the same problem...